# getting server time by Ajax - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tcl

I made a button that is when pressed it brings the server time ,,,so there is this html and js file and I want it to get time from time.tcl file , please assist me with it :

1.my file using html and Javascript :

```
    <html>

    <body>

     <input value="Get Time" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:showCurrentTime()' name="GetTime">
     <div id="result" align="center"></div>

     <script language="Javascript">

     function showCurrentTime()
     {
     var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
    else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject(“Microsoft.XMLHTTP”);
}

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  } else  {// code for IE6, IE5  
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject(“Microsoft.XMLHTTP”);}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

    xmlhttp.open(“GET”,”time.tcl”,true); 

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

2.my time.tcl file :

```
    set now [clock seconds]
    # print default-formatted time
    puts [clock format $now]
    # print custom formatted time
    set fmt "Today is day %j of the current year."
    puts [clock format $now -format $fmt]

    set today [clock seconds]
    set fmt "%Y-%m-%d"
    puts "The current date is [clock format $today -format $fmt]."
```

Comment: Can you describe what _actually_ happens and what you think _ought_ to happen?

Comment: First issue that I see: the `onclick` handler does not need a `javascript:`.

Comment: What URL do you need to access "time.tcl"?

Comment: @Donal Fellows first thanks for concern ,,I want it to get the time of the server , the tcl file is running well ,,, but when i call it by js it does not respond .. I mean when I press the form button the tcl file should run and write the server time but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think these quote marks `“ ”` inside the open functions are valid, semantics

Have you tried replacing

```
xmlhttp.open(“GET”,”time.tcl”,true);
```

with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","time.tcl",true);
```